# PowerBI - Integrate Custom Visual Tiles to my WebApp

Tags: rest, powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

I included different Tiles/Reports to my WebApp from PowerBI, according to this documentation:

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-integrate-a-power-bi-tile-or-report/#gettile

Everything runs fine, but when I include a Custom Visual Tile, it appears an error Message "*this visual type is not yet supported or cannot be displayed due to security reasons*".

Does anybody know how to solve that or any suggestions ? Is there an option/property for custom visuals ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not yet supported. We're are aware of this limitation and will provide a solution. Could you create an item on [ideas.powerbi.com](https://ideas.powerbi.com) to track this ask?

Comment: Thanks - will do that.

Comment: Is this implemented yet?